# Sending data and text input using ajax (Pure Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a simple form that takes user input such as name and file input for cv upload.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<input type="file" id="cv" name="cv">
```

i can get the text to be posted via ajax alone, and also the file alone to be posted to the receiving but not both at the same time which is exactly what i want how do i do this using pure js. No jquery please

```
xmlhttp.open('POST','fileajax.php',true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(encodeURI('name='+ sname.value));
```

The above works for just text input

```
file = scv.files[0];
formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file1",file);

    xmlhttp.open('POST','fileajax.php',true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

this works for just file. How do i send both text and file in one ajax request. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the append() even for text

```
formData.append("name", sname.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could send text by url parameter for example

```
xmlhttp.open('POST','fileajax.php?text=abc',true);
```

Comment: thats a smart one, didnt think of that. I'ld give it a try rightnow

Comment: POST doesn't use variables in url, this is GET.

Comment: it is actually working in my past experience on ajax

Comment: it does work, i just have to change the receiving php to get the url data.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help Ma Yubo. Really learnt alot today. But Lorenzo's answer seems more conventional.